# Win 10 file search - Wildcards after name parameter

Tags: search, windows-10, wildcard, windows-explorer

I have plenty of text files in a directory. I would like to get only those which contain specific string in the name. The problem is, the string can be also found in the files content, so on searching by simple `*M40` I get some files which names does not fit the criteria (but their content does).

Normally the solution here would be using `name:` parameter, but it seems to ignore asterisk before the string and I only get the files which names start with the given string.

Is there any way to have wildcards working when searching only the names (ignoring content)?